# What is the suitable data type for DB replication?

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a DB using SQL Server 2008.

This DB will be used in two countries and at some time (every day) they will be synchronized, I'll use the Replication service to accomplish that.

Most of the tables are using an Int column with Identity increment. But the tables will be empty when deployed so both countries will have a row with identity 1, 2, and son. I've never use replication before so I wanna know if there will be an error when the tables are synchronized?

Should I use a GUID data type instead?

Answer (score 1):

[Replicate Identity Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152543.aspx) (MSDN):

> Replication offers three identity range management options:
>
> - Automatic. Used for merge replication and transactional replication with updates at the Subscriber...
> - Manual. Used for snapshot and transactional replication without updates at the Subscriber...
> - None. This option is recommended only for backwards compatibility...

So, yes, you can continue to use `IDENTITY`, provided you read through the information on replication and choose an option that makes sense for you.

Under Automatic, what it does is each server grabs a range of usable identity values and hands the individual values out as needed. Provided synchronization occurs often enough so that the ranges aren't completely exhausted, you'll never notice this detail.

And this allows you to scale out later as needed - as opposed to e.g. a `MOD` scheme where one server hands out odd values and the other even - you can't easily add a third server to such a scheme.

Answer (score 0):

By your description, it sounds like you want to implement so called Merge replication.
In SQL Server you would not need to change the identity to a GUID, however, if you don't SQL server will automatically add another column called rowguid for each table and you may end up with duplicates of your original identity column. To circumvent this, you could have the servers assign mod 2 IDs.

In my opinion it makes most sense to use a GUID for the IDs altogether. Don't forget to set the ROWGUIDCOL property on your identity columns. Good luck.

Relevant MSDN:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a deviceID field to all tables users can update.  With each device making changes using its own ID as part of the PK, there cannot be conflicts across devices.